# How do I add an object in a array / matrix at a certain location in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a matrix consisting of four lists. How do I add, for example, the number 9 to location row 2, column 2?

Right now I add 0 and 8 depending on whether the letters in my strings s and t match, but I actually have to add a digit from another location in the matrix.

- If the letters in the strings match, I have to add the digit on the top left, so on location 1,1, if the letters 0,0 of my two strings match, I have to add the digit that is on location 0,0 in the matrix.
- If they don't match, I have to compare the three digits that are on the left, top left and top of the current location, take the smallest one, add 1 and put it at that location.

So my problem is how do I 'Reach' thos digits? What do I put in the place of my 0's and 8's?

```
I=[]
s = 'abcd'
t = 'abdd'

n = len(s)+1
m = len(t)+1

for row in range(n):
    new_row= list()
    for column in range(m):
        if row==0:
            new_row.append(column)    
        elif column ==0:
            new_row.append(row)      
        elif s[row-1]==t[column-1]:      
            new_row.append(0)        
        elif s[row-1]!=t[column-1]:
            new_row.append(8)       

    I.append(new_row)

print(I)
```

Comment: You're likely to get more help if you share some data AND what you've tried in terms of code.

Comment: yes please show us a bit of code and your expected result.

Comment: Hey, I just added the information and my code.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
M[1][1] += 9
```